# Munich and Vienna Malt

Tags: malt, ingredients, recipe, flavor

How do these two malts differ?  I can find sources at times with slightly different colors and I know there must be flavor differences.

I was wondering if anyone could shed light on how the two are produced and what the flavor impressions are of each one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chez, you're in luck. I just wrapped up a double 1-gallon experiment with these two malts. Had the brew-bug one day & two 55 pound sacks of malt.

My experiment was simple. I made gallon batches of 1.040 OG beer solely from each malt. Hopping was kept to a single 60 minute addition of about 20 IBUs.  I selected a clean ale yeast and fermented cool to minimize its influence.  Both brews finished around 1.011 SG.

### Munich Malt

#### Aroma

Toasty notes. A little grainy sweetness.

#### Appearance

Tanish-amber in color. Tan head.

#### Flavor

Grainy, toasty. Leans to the dry side, with just a little malt sweetness.

### Vienna Malt

#### Aroma

Grain sweetness up front

#### Appearance

Paler than the Munich beer.

#### Flavor

Biscuit. Has a soft (or smooth) sweetness but not cloying.

Answer (score 11):

Based on a standard Pilsner Malt, for Vienna the barley gets watered some more (44-46% water instead of 42-46%). Also the roasting is slightly higher at 90°C instead of 80-85°C. Munich is made with still more water (up to 47%) and temepratures up to 110°C. Water and higher temperatures lead to a more pronounced Maillard-Reaction and hence formation of darker colour and caramel taste.

Comment: Thanks for rounding out my post by answering the first part of the question.

Comment: This is a great addition to the first answer by dean.  Very complete.  I wish I could vote for these answers again!